# Logging Magento 1.9 database queries. What doe the

Tags: magento-1.9, database, debugging

With the below code, what does "#0000000005dc945b000055af41b2fb74#" from lines 5 and 6 represent? Is this related to the PID or session hash? Any idea.

This code is taken from database queries after editing the file "lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php" as mentioned in https://firebearstudio.com/blog/the-complete-guide-to-magento-debugging.html

````
#5 Mage_Sales_Model_Quote[Mage_Core_Model_Abstract]#0000000005dc945b000055af41b2fb74#->save() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php:1966]
#6 Mage_Sales_Model_Quote#0000000005dc945b000055af41b2fb74#->save() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php:380]
#7 Webshopapps_Adminshipping_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create[Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create]#0000000005dc9424000055af41b2fb74#->initFromOrder(&Amasty_Orderattr_Model_Sales_Order#0000000005dc949d000055af41b2fb74#) called at [app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/CreateController.php:358]
#8 Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController#0000000005dc97d2000055af41b2fb74#->reorderAction() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php:418]
#9 Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController[Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action]#0000000005dc97d2000055af41b2fb74#->dispatch('reorder') called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php:254]
#10 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Admin[Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard]#0000000005dc971c000055af41b2fb74#->match(&Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http#0000000005dc971a000055af41b2fb74#) called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:172]
#11 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front#0000000005dc97c6000055af41b2fb74#->dispatch() called at [app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:354]
#12 Mage_Core_Model_App#0000000005dc9758000055af41b2fb74#->run(array('scope_code' => '', 'scope_type' => 'store', 'options' => array())) called at [app/Mage.php:684]
#13 Mage::run('', 'store') called at [index.php:89]```
````